# substring not found error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run my code I get the error substring not found, I've looked through the code multiple times and don't understand what is wrong with it and how to fix it? Thankyou.

Code:

```
key = "cats"
tkey = ""
message = "Are awesome animals!"
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for p,k in zip(message,key):
    char = alphabet.index(p)
    temp = alphabet.index(k)
    newchar = char + temp
    if newchar > 25:
        newchar -= 25
    newchar = alphabet[newchar]
    tkey.append(newchar)
print (newchar)
```

Comment: there are no capital letters in your alphabet. use `alphabet.index(p.lower())` and `alphabet.index(k.lower())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't allow for capitals.  Change the loop string like this:

```
for p, k in zip(message.lower(), key):
```

You will also run into trouble with the tkey accumulation: strings don't have an append method.  Use simple concatenation for now (you'll learn about *join* soon enough):

```
    tkey += newchar
print (newchar)
```

Finally, you'll have to add a line or two to handle the spaces; they're not covered in your current logic, and they'll also get the "not found" error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the first letter of `message` is `A`, which is not in the alphabet:

```
>>> alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> alphabet.index('A')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

Depending on what you want, you may want to lowercase the input before testing:

```
char = alphabet.index(p.lower())
```

Or lower case the whole message before.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code, in the `for` loop you start with

```
p = "A", k="c"
```

and so

```
char = alphabet.index(p)
```

fails to find anything in `alphabet` to match the `A`. You have no way to fail gracefully so it dies.

You can either catch the error and deal with it, or you can standardize the case of your strings.

Comment: Facepalm, can't believe I didn't notice something so simple. Thanks